# How to read multiple csv in python and get one csv as output

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I had already asked the question how to solve it in pandas. But now I need a non pandas version.

My Code

```
import glob
import os

## path
path = r'C:/x/x/Desktop/xxx/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))

## column
column_headers = ['Date', 'Time', 'Duration', 'IP', 'Request']

## open only one csv. -- I want to read here not only 1 file --
## my approach:
## with open(all_files) as log, ....
with open('log.csv') as log, open('out355.csv', 'w') as out:
    out.write(';'.join(column_headers)+'\n') 
    while True:
        try:
            lines = [next(log).strip('\n').split(' ',4) for i in range(6)][3:]
            out.write(';'.join(lines[1][:2]+[l[4] for l in lines])+'\n')
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Since I'm new to python, I can not just modify my running code just so well. So I would be glad if I would get the complete code.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I would be glad if I would get the complete code"* - SO isn't a code-writing service, we aren't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: you'd be better off with the `csv` module!!

Comment: Thank you for your downvote, I wrote that I am a newbie in python. And this is not my homework .. have a nice day :)

Comment: please, think like computer, we need input and we get you output, so, post your csv data, state you wanted output, and point which part you get problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're a "newbie", it doesn't matter whether it's set as homework or your requirement comes from somewhere else, **this is not a code-writing service**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should at least *attempt* your own work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, you need to read each of the `*.csv` files and concat them. So you'd have to open a new file and read each of the csv files using glob. Ensure that when you do this there is a trailing new line in each of the csv files at the end of it, or you'd end up with the last line of `file_x` and first data line of `file_x+1` on the same line

```
from glob import glob

with open('combined.csv', 'a') as combinedFile:
    combinedFile.write('a,b,c,d,e\n') # Headers
    for eachFile in glob('*.csv'):
        if eachFile == 'combined.csv':
            pass
        else:
            count = 0
            for line in open(eachFile, 'r'):
                if count != 0: # So that you don't read 1st line of every file if it contains the headers.
                    combinedFile.write(line)
                count = 1
```

Runtime:

a.csv

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

b.csv

```
a,b,c,d,e
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
```

combined.csv

```
a,b,c,d,e    
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
```

Comment: hi Sudheesh. Thanks for your Solution! I want to add a regex in my code. where should i place that? I want only write Strings in to the csv, where i match with my regex: [\0-9]+[ s] Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
with open('out355.csv', 'w') as out:
  for csvfile in all_files:
    with open(csvfile) as log:
      out.write(...)
      .. the rest of your script ..
```

Answer (score -1):

This Should work

```
import glob
import os

## path
path = r'C:/x/x/Desktop/xxx/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))

## column
column_headers = ['Date', 'Time', 'Duration', 'IP', 'Request']

out = open('out355.csv', 'w')
out.write(';'.join(column_headers)+'\n')
for file_ in all_files:
    log = open(file_)
    while True:
        try:
            lines = [next(log).strip('\n').split(' ',4) for i in range(6)][3:]
            out.write(';'.join(lines[1][:2]+[l[4] for l in lines])+'\n')
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Comment: thanks for your solution! the code genarete a new output csv, the column names are written, but the file is empty..What can that be?

Comment: there is some issue with your script in try block. can you please tell me if it was working for single file